# Separate UserStore By Client

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using Identityserver4 and ASPIdentity for user management. I want users dont have access to all applications(clients). I'm going to add table like UserClients, which specifies allowed applications for user. I'm interested in your advice, whether it is possible and does not conflict with the principles of SSO?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer takes care of client access configuration and user authentication, but not of authorization at client/user level.

Users are not bound to a client. Thus, as you've noticed, all users have access to a client. IdentityServer authenticates the user, regardless which client is used or whether the user logs in at IdentityServer directly.

So it is the client (and also api) that has to authorize the user.

It doesn't matter if the user is already authenticated (SSO) or not. It is the responsibility of the client / api to determine whether the user is authorized. In order to solve this 'problem' they've build the [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/), to decouple authentication and authorization.

By adding middleware (as done in PolicyServer) you can grant or deny a user access.

You can add some discriminator in IdentityServer, e.g. a specific claim type / role, use a seperate authorization server or use resource based authorization, e.g. when a (business) user is present then the user has access.

In the end, authorization is done by the resource that needs to be protected, because only the resource can interpret the claims and business rules.

All you have to do is short-circuit the pipeline in case the *authenticated* user has no access.

It's perfectly fine if you want to 'disable' SSO. Simply ignore the IdentityServer cookie (in the client), thus forcing the user to login (for that client).

But you should not deny authentication (e.g. return invalid login) when the user has no access to the client / resource.

That's why there is http status 401 Unauthorized and 403 Forbidden. So you can notify the user that it is not authorized to use this client.

---

Regarding your setup, in your case you can also add claims to the UserClaims table (instead of creating an additional table) to configure the allowed apps, e.g. user A:

```
http://mycompany/appname = app1
http://mycompany/appname = app2
http://mycompany/appname = app3
```

Add the ClaimType to the IdentityClaims table and the ApiClaims table in order to make sure the claims make it to the access / identity token.

Add middleware in the client / resource or add business rules (policies) where you check the claimtype and required value. If not present then deny access. E.g. app1 should look for the required claim type `http://mycompany/appname` with the value 'app1'.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll try this solution